# Lesser no. of lines of code in actual .scss file as compared to what dev tools show

Tags: css, sass, devtools

I wanted to change a css property in my .scss file from the developer tools. As I inspect the respective element, I can see in the `styles` panel, the corresponding properties mentioned below the corresponding .scss file name and line number. When I click it, I don't see the same styles.

In the picture below, the name of the file links to line number 295, which should display properties `display` and `box-shadow`, or any other variable if its using.

[image]

but what it is showing after clicking on that link is this:

[image]

There are these `h1` and `h2` styles that are showing before and after line number 295 and a curly bracket at line 295 itself. Also, the actual no. of lines of code in the `main.scss` file are only 966 :

[image]

But in the `styles` tab, the line number in the links is greater than the total no. of lines in the actual main.scss file: (in the following picture, its showing line no. 1208, but there's only 966 line, and when I click it, I don't see the corresponding exact properties like it should be).

[image]

I am new to developer tools, neither have I ever used sass before. I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: In order to DevTools "know" the position of an original code, it utilizes .map file (or map info embedded into CSS); if the maps are not updated to the latest changes, it will fail

Comment: Is it Chrome Dev Tools?